# text-align:justify is not getting applied

Tags: css, text-align, justify

I have added the following code sample in my .html file:

```
<div Class="Frame" Style="left:85.8pt; top:198.5pt; width:415.5pt; height:43pt; position:absolute; background-color:rgb(201,201,201); overflow:hidden; border:0px Solid rgb(0,0,0);">
<p Style="text-align:justify; text-align-last:justify; padding-top:0pt; padding-bottom:0pt;">
<span Style="height:14.4pt; width:415.5pt;" class="ln">
<span Style="font-size:12pt; font-family:F0; word-spacing:5.09135818481445em; letter-spacing:0em; color: rgb(0,0,0);">Sample Text Here</span>
</span>
</p>
</div>
```

But the text-align:justify is not getting applied.

Comment: Do you want to get something like : http://jsfiddle.net/dkG3Z/ ?

Comment: i am getting "center align", "right align" and "left align" properly applied. but not getting only "justify". Here also, if i apply text-align:justify; it is not giving me justified text. instead it is left-align.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the text-align on the `span` element.

```
<span Style="font-size:12pt; font-family:F0; word-spacing:0.29135818481445em; letter-spacing:0em; color: rgb(0,0,0);text-align: justify;">text</span>
```

You can see it at:
http://jsfiddle.net/dkG3Z/2/

Comment: No, its not giving me expected results. You have used word-spacing:0.29135818481445em but i am using word-spacing:5.09135818481445em. is it affecting? what if i dont want to use word-spacing.

Comment: word-spacing: 5.09135818481445em means the space between words will be fixed. I used a smaller value for the text to be readable. If your goal is to get aligned text that's readable you should not use word-spacing in this scenario. Check: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dkG3Z/5/) is that what you were looking for?

Comment: ok. it is not giving me justified output. i thought to adjust space between the words to fake it like applied justify, but it is very hard to process for each words of each line

Comment: i am not getting the text justified so i made it by appling word spacing so that it look like justified applied. but text is flowing out of "frame" width

Comment: Okey if you want to use the word-spacing solution you should put `max-width:` on your `<p>`. That will do the trick of limiting the text so that it does not go out of fram width.

Answer (score 0):

you have a few issues here. First paragraph and span tags do not stretch/span across an object (page or other element) they wrap around the content. The best way to think of this is like shrink wrap or plastic wrapping around something. You need to apply the text align to a div element and have your content added there. If you are using css3 you can use the following:

```css
div
    {
        text-align:justify;
        text-justify:inter-word;
    }
```

```html
<!--and then your html would be something like-->
<div>here is some text</div>
```

When you re-scale your browser window you will see how justify works. The second attribute `text-justify:inter-word` controls how much the text scales between words as the browser is resized